# Symfony2 entity choice issue

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

I have an `entity` form field in my Symfony2 project.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('productId', 'genemu_jquerychosen_entity', array(
        'class' => 'EMRSabaBundle:Product',
        'property' => 'name'
    ))
    ;
}
```

The `Product` entity has some objects like price, name, mode, & id
I want to let user choose the product by name & see chosen produc's price, then submit product ID, not name.

Is there any soloution?

Answer (score 3):

As per the documentation for this bundle:

> You can use all the core choice types from Symfony (choice, country,
>   ...) and Doctrine (ORM and ODM), you just have to prefix the type name
>   with genemu_jqueryselect2_*

This means you are using a "regular" `entity` field. You can do what you want by skipping the definition of `property` and relying on the `__toString()` method from `EMRSabaBundle:Product`:

> **[property]**
>
> This is the property that should be used for displaying the entities
>   as text in the HTML element. If left blank, the entity object will be
>   cast into a string and so must have a __toString() method.

Change your code to:

```
$builder->add('productId', 'genemu_jquerychosen_entity', array(
        'class' => 'EMRSabaBundle:Product'
    ))
```

And define the `_toString()` method in your `EMRSabaBundle:Product` object as follow:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->name . ' (' . $this->price . ')';
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property